# Method declared out side the class is included automatically?

Tags: ruby

Can someone help me make sense of the following? I have the following code in test.rb:

```
class Dog
end
// bark is declared outside of Dog class
def bark
  puts 'Woof!'
end
```

then in irb:

```
>> source 'test.rb'
>> a = Dog.new
=> #<Dog:0x117f614>
>> a.bark
Woof!
=> nil
```

Why does method `bark` exist in Dog instance even though it is declared outside of the class? Because it's in the same file? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a method in the "global" scope (outside of any class), that method is made a private method of Object:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

class Dog
end

p Object.respond_to?(:bark, true)     # => false

def bark
  puts "Woof!"
end

p Object.respond_to?(:bark, true)     # => true
```

Object is in the ancestry chain of all objects, including Dog:

```
dog = Dog.new
p dog.class.name               # => "Dog"
p dog.class.superclass.name    # => "Object"
```

Therefore dogs (and indeed all objects) now know how to bark.  However, the method being private, you'll have to use instance_eval to call it with an explicit receiver:

```
dog.instance_eval { bark  }    # => "Woof!"
```

Or you can call it with an implicit receiver with no gymnastics needed:

```
bar    # => "Woof!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your exact example doesn't work in Ruby 1.9. (Apart from the bad comment syntax.)

However, declaring a method in the top level scope will make it a private method on `Object`, apparently:

```
>> Object.private_methods.include? :bark
=> true
```

Perhaps in your Ruby (1.8?), this is a public method?

Comment: It's not public in 1.8 either.  I don't know why the OP's code did not complain "private method bark called...".  It has something to do with the irb "source" line.  I don't know what that does differently than "require".

Comment: (In 1.8.7) this seems to hold true -- if I require instead of source, I do indeed get that error.  Source is presumably the same as the Bash builtin, that includes the contents of the file as if it had been typed -- therefore a private method would be accessible.